# Why is better to use different containers for frontend and backend application? i.e. net core 3.0 backend and angular 8 frontend

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, web-deployment

My doubt is simple.

What is more convinient technically and why?

One container exclusive for Angular app and one for the Backend or one container for All ?

What's  the usuall choice?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Separate containers for release and one for development.

Since containers are mostly for releases, then try to go with separate.

Reasons:

1. On deployment you might want to place api on a separate virtual network for security. (DMZ etc).
2. Static content (angular) might want to go to cdn or storage. Why couple it on IIS?
3. Scaling out api's, makes sense. Scaling out static content doesn't.
4. Api's might need to be handled by api management in the future.  Better to have it separate and expose an ip from management without needing to assign an external ip or host name

Answer (score 1):

**Separate containers** for all your stages, for release and development, one for the Angular application and one for the Backend application.

Since they are different applications, it is recommended to use one container for each; for scalability, isolation, monitoring and versioning reasons it is way better to use different containers.

@Athanasios Kataras why do you recommend to use separate containers for release and not for development? Release architecture should be similar to development one, if possible.